# Delete substrings started with 'vi-' within string

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I go from 'mystr' to 'result'. I believe it can be done with regular expressions but I don't know how to do it.

**mystr**

```
var mystr = 'football vi-cnn-sel vi-sky test vi-axn red';
```

**result**

```
var result = 'football test red';
```

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47350982/edit) and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see **[ask]**.

Comment: Peter I understand your message but as I have written on the question I really have no knowledge of regex. I choose not to put it than to put something meaningless or absurd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex [`\b(vi\-\[a-zA-Z\-\]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/l40kWZ/2).

And trim your result string of multiple spaces with `+(?= )`

```js
var mystr = 'football vi-cnn-sel vi-sky test vi-axn red vitest';
var result = mystr.replace(/\bvi\-[a-zA-Z\-]*/g,'').replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string and filter out the words that match

```
var mystr = 'football vi-cnn-sel vi-sky test vi-axn red';

mystr.split(' ').filter(function(v){
   if(!v.match("vi-")){
     return v;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/( vi-\S+)/g` regex and replace all found occurrences by an empty String.

```js
var myStr = "football vi-cnn-sel vi-sky test vi-axn red";
var result = myStr.replace(/( vi-\S+)/gi, "");
console.log(result);
```

1. `S+` - matches all white-space characters
2. `g` - matches all occurrences (doesn't stop on the first found)
3. `i` - use case-insensitive matching (not sure if you need it). You can remove it if it's not necessary